# Combinations of list elements

Tags: combinatorics, lisp, elisp

It was written in Emacs Lisp and requires Common Lisp loop facility.

Can this code be improved? Did I hit any anti-patterns along the way?

```
(defun combos (list)
  (let* ((a (car list))
         (d (cdr list))
         (s (and d (combos d)))
         (v (loop for c in s collect (cons a c))))
    (cons (list a) (append s v))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest handling a nil input explicitly. Then you can:

- strip out the `and` (in `s`'s binding), and just recurse directly
- strip out the `cons` at the bottom, leaving only the `append`

Here's the code I tested with (in Scheme, since I have neither Emacs nor a CL implementation installed):

```
;; Requires SRFI 26
(define (combos lst)
  (if (null? lst) '(())
      (let* ((a (car lst))
             (d (cdr lst))
             (s (combos d))
             (v (map (cut cons a <>) s)))
        (append s v))))
```

And if you *really* can't bear to see the empty list as one of the combinations (though it really is), just take the `cdr` of the resulting list. It's always the first element.

---

**Update:** I installed Emacs now, so I was able to port my Scheme version to elisp and test it:

```
(defun combos (list)
  (if (null list) '(nil)
      (let* ((a (car list))
             (d (cdr list))
             (s (combos d))
             (v (mapcar (lambda (x) (cons a x)) s)))
        (append s v))))
```

Comment: Elisp is a Lisp2, so there's no need to misspell `list` as `lst` just to avoid shadowing the built-in function.

Comment: @GarethRees Of course. But I'm a Schemer, and Scheme habits die hard. Like the tendency to want to do everything with a named `let` or `syntax-case` macros. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Two important problems:

1. Your function could be better named: it returns a list of the non-empty subsets of its argument, so it should be called something like `non-empty-subsets`.
2. There's no docstring.

I think the most natural way to implement this function is to implement `subsets` (which is straightforward) and then drop the empty subset:

```
(defun subsets (list)
  "Return a list of the subsets of LIST."
  (if (null list) '(nil)
    (let ((e (car list))
          (ss (subsets (cdr list))))
      (append ss (loop for s in ss collect (cons e s))))))

(defun non-empty-subsets (list)
  "Return a list of the non-empty subsets of LIST."
  (cdr (subsets list)))
```

But tastes differ, so you might legitimately prefer your original version.

Comment: Very succinct. I like.